# Asp.net IIS6 - application pool recycle

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I'm running an ASP.NET website on Windows 2003 IIS 6.0

Every 24-28 hours I'm getting the following error:

When the error occurrs all users are disconnected from the website.

```
Event Type: Warning
Event Source:   W3SVC
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1013
Date:       02/02/2010
Time:       19:29:38
User:       N/A

A process serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' exceeded time limits during 
shut down. The process id was '1660'. 

For more information, see Help and Support Center at   
   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Any idea what does the error means?

Is this related to application pool recycle?

If so, is it a "must" to recycle the IIS app pool?

Comment: Possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411918/iis-apppool-error-1013-w3svc

Comment: not quite the same as the other is a forced recycle by IIS, this is a normal recycle.

Comment: Forced or not, application pool recycle is there, and you should then avoid in-process session mode (which means the new worker process does not keep previous sessions). That change of design can guarantee you won't get "all users are disconnected from the website". The latter is an issue, while the recycle is innocent.

Comment: Did one of the answers answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yep this is IIS running a clean up, and recycling the app pool. you can change how this works by changing the setting on the applicationn pool..

[IIS 6 Configuring Worker Processes for Recycling](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778695%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by deadlocks on the threadpool for your application. You may need to adjust the worker threads in your machine.config or alter that recycling settings adjust how often/when the recycling occurs based on processes or virtual memory.

[Contention, poor performance, and deadlocks when you make Web service requests from ASP.NET applications](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268)

Comment: Unless further information is collected, I personally don't think it is a good idea to follow that KB article. Such warnings in event logs are generally harmless (if no other errors are observed at the same time).